# Interpreting & modifying Perl one-liner?

Tags: perl, email

I have the following Perl 'one-liner' script (found it online, so not mine):

```
perl -lsne '
    /$today.* \[([0-9.]+)\]:.+dovecot_(?:login|plain):([^\s]+).* for (.*)/
    and $sender{$2}{r}+=scalar (split / /,$3)
    and $sender{$2}{i}{$1}=1;

    END {
        foreach $sender(keys %sender){
            printf"Recip=%05d Hosts=%03d Auth=%s\n",
                $sender{$sender}{r},
                scalar (keys %{$sender{$sender}{i}}),
                $sender;
        }
    }
' -- -today=$(date +%F) /var/log/exim_mainlog | sort
```

I've been trying to understand its innards, because I would like to modify it to re-use its functionality.

Some questions I got:

- What does the flag *-lsne* does? (From what I know, it's got to be, at least, 3 different flags in one)
- Where does *$sender* gets its value from?
- What about that *(?:login|plain)* segment, are they 'variables'? (I get that's ReGex, I'm just not familiarized with it)

What I'm trying to achieve:

- Get the number of emails sent by each user in a SMTP relay *periodically* (cron job)
- If there's an irregular number of emails (say, 500 in a 1-hour timespan), *do something* (like shutting of the service, or send a notification)

**Why** I'm trying to achieve this:
Lately, someone has been using my SMTP server to send spam, so I would like to monitor email activity so they stop abusing the SMTP relay resources. *(Security-related suggestions are always welcomed, but out of topic for this question. Trying to focus on the script for now)*

What I'm **NOT** trying to achieve:

- To get the script done by third-parties. (Just try and point me in the right direction, maybe an example)

So, any suggestions, guidance,and friendly comments are welcomed. I understand this may be an *out-of-topic* question, yet I've been struggling with this for almost a week and my background with Perl is null.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `-l`, `-s`, `-n` and `-e` are documented in perlrun

Comment: `foreach $sender(...)` aliases `$sender` to each element of the lists over which the foreach iterates. But I think you might have been asking about `%sender`, whose elements are set by the assignment operators (`+=` and `=`).

Comment: Regular expression `(?:login|plain)` matches `login` and `plain`.

Comment: There is a fashion for writing multiple-line "one-line" Perl programs. While it's fine to do this to yourself, just as you may write unindented code with one-letter identifiers and without `use strict` or brushing your teeth in your private moments, I believe it is very bad manners to subject anyone else to stuff like this. Yes @Xanagandr I realise that this isn't your own code, and I am sympathising. Someone is showing off at your expense, and I am saying this in the hope that others will stop doing it. Amongst other things it's very unportable and spits at Windows  users.

Comment: @ikegami Thanks for both inputs on this.

Comment: @Borodin Yeah, I'm no fan of one-liners, either. My main approach would have been a python script, since I know nothing of Perl.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-MO=Deparse` is your friend for understanding one-liners (and one liners that wrap into five lines on your terminal):

```
$ perl -MO=Deparse -lsne '/$today.* \[([0-9.]+)\]:.+dovecot_( ...

BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }

LINE:

while ( defined($_ = <ARGV>) ) {

    chomp $_;

    $sender{$2}{'i'}{$1} = 1 if
        /$today.* \[([0-9.]+)\]:.+dovecot_(?:login|plain):([^\s]+).* for (.*)/
            and $sender{$2}{'r'} += scalar split(/ /, $3, 0);

    sub END {

        foreach $sender (keys %sender) {

            printf "Recip=%05d Hosts=%03d Auth=%s\n", 
                $sender{$sender}{'r'}, 
                scalar keys %{$sender{$sender}{'i'};}, $sender;
        }
    }
}

-e syntax OK
```

[newlines and indentation added for clarity]

Comment: @mob: Thanks for that. I am nowhere near a command line of any sort and could not be sure of the expansion.

Comment: The whole thing looks rather wrong to me. The regex pattern starts with `$today`, which is undefined. Nothing can work properly after that.

Comment: `$today` is set by `perl -s ... -- -today=$(date %F)`

Comment: @mob Really appreciate this answer. I can feel I understand this code better with the indentation. Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure how that explains anything. For example, you replaced `-l` with `BEGIN { $/ = "\n"; $\ = "\n"; }` which is far more cryptic. You also don't cover `-s`, `(?:login|plain)` or `$sender` at all, despite being the three questions the OP asked!

Answer (score 2):

**What does the flag -lsne does? (From what I know, it's got to be, at least, 3 different flags in one)**

- `-l` causes lines of input read in to be auto-chomped, and lines of
  output printed out to have "\n" auto-appended
- `-s` enables switch
  parsing. This is what creates the variable `$today`, because a
  command-line switch of `--today=$(date +%F)` was passed.
- `-n` surrounds the entire "one-liner" in a `while (<>) { ... }` loop. 
  Effectively reading every line from standard input and running the
  body of the one liner on that line
- `-e` is the switch that tells
  `perl` to execute the following code from the command line, rather
  than running a file containing Perl code

**Where does $sender gets its value from?**

I suspect you are confusing `$sender` with `%sender`.  The code uses `$sender{$2}{r}` without explicitly mentioning `%sender`.  This is a function of Perl called "auto-vivification".  Basically, because we used `$sender{$2}{r}`, perl automatically created a variable `%sender`, and added a key whose name is whatever is in `$2`, and set the value of that key in `%sender` to be a reference to a new hash. It then set that new hash to have a key `'r'` and a value of `scalar (split / /,$3)`

**What about that (?:login|plain) segment, are they 'variables'? (I get that's ReGex, I'm just not familiarized with it)**

It's saying that this portion of the regular expression will match either `'login'` or `'plain'`.  The `?:` at the beginning tells Perl that these parentheses are used only for clustering, not capturing.  In other words, the result of this portion of the pattern match will not be stored in the `$1`, `$2`, `$3`, etc variables.

Answer (score 1):

> What does the flag -lsne does? (From what I know, it's got to be, at least, 3 different flags in one)

You can access a summary of the available perl command line options by running '~$ perl -h' in the terminal. Below are filtered out the specific command line options you were asking about.

```
~$ perl -h|perl -ne 'print if /^\s+(-l|-s|-n|-e)/'
   -e program        one line of program (several -e's allowed, omit programfile)
   -l[octal]         enable line ending processing, specifies line terminator
   -n                assume "while (<>) { ... }" loop around program
   -s                enable rudimentary parsing for switches after programfile
```

Two examples of the '-s' command line option in use.

```
~$ perl -se 'print "Todays date is $today\n"' -- -today=`date +%F`
Todays date is 2016-10-17

~$ perl -se 'print "The sky is $color.\n"' -- -color='blue'
The sky is blue.
```

For detailed explanations of those command line options read the online documentation below.
http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html

Or run the command below from your terminal.

```
~$ perldoc perlrun
```

Unrelated to the questions of the OP, I'm aware that this is not a complete answer (added as much as I was able to at the moment), so if this post/answer violates any SO rules, the moderators should remove it. Thx.

Comment: I don't know, but there's several nuggets of valuable information for Perl beginners. I appreciate your effort.